# Apply the same css only for simple page products ( veriable or normal) - WooCommerce

Tags: css, wordpress

hello i add a new button for buy now in theme.simple product page the style every button in his line  .  but in the veriable product the 2 button are in same line look the picture i want make the same style of normal product  .
[image: normal product][image: veriable product]
i need help for this thank you so mush

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: http://cambobello.com/produit/swag-pant-gris/

Comment: this is link of veriable product

Comment: http://cambobello.com/produit/frederic-caps-rouge/

Comment: link of normal product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display : block;` also shown below or add to the class used in that div.

```
<div class="woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart variations_button woocommerce-variation-add-to-cart-disabled" style="display: block;">
</div>
```

[image]

End result

[image]

Hope this helps

Comment: yes that work !! juste i should take all the groupe of classes  thank you for help .